# How can i remove emoji's from text using xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-3.0

I have a **$text** = "Hello  üäö$"

I wanted to remove just emoji's from the text using **xquery**. How can i do that?

expected result : "Hello üäö$"

i tried to use:

```
replace($text, '[^\x00-\xFFFF]', '')
```

but didn't work.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: XQuery uses the XML escape convention `&#xFFFF;`, not the C/Java escape convention `\xFFFF`.

Answer (score 5):

To replace emoji, you can make use of XPath's support for [Character Class Escapes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cces), specifically Category and Block Escapes, to match named Unicode blocks:

```
replace("Hello  üäö$", "\p{IsEmoticons}", "")
```

This returns the expected result:

```
Hello  üäö$
```

The "Emoticons" block doesn't contain all characters commonly associated with "emoji." For example,  (Purple Heart, U+1F49C), according to a site like https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F49C that lets you look up Unicode character information, is from:

> Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs, U+1F300 - U+1F5FF

This block is not available in XPath or XQuery processors, since it is neither listed in the XML Schema 1.0 spec linked above, nor is it in [Unicode block names for use in XSD regular expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsd-unicode-blocknames/)—a list of blocks that XPath and XQuery processors conforming to XML Schema 1.1 are [required to support](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#cces-blockesc).

For characters from blocks not available in XPath or XQuery, you can manually construct character classes. For example, given the purple heart character above, we can match it as follows:

```
replace("Purple  heart", "[&#x1F300;-&#x1F5FF;]", "")
```

This returns the expected result:

```
Purple  Heart
```

If you're wondering why we use `&#x1F300;` and not `U+1F300` or `\x1F300`, it is because, as Michael Kay noted above, "XQuery uses the XML escape convention `&#xFFFF;`, not the C/Java escape convention `\xFFFF`."

(I've updated the answer in response to the other very helpful comments.)

Comment: If you match against `"\p{IsEmoticons}"` then also single emojis will be replaced.

Comment: if i use replace("Hello    üäö$", "\p{IsEmoticons}+", ""), it only removes smiley emojis, how can i remove all of them from query?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address characters outside of the Emoticons block.